# How to merge with groupBy in php laravel when i have two array(one of them have all data in attribute)ac

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

[image: up]

How to merge with groupBy in php laravel when i have two array(one of them have all data in attribute)

One array doesnt have attribute and another props

or can i transform array to similar array?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) on your [Eloquent collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections).

```
User::all()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the eloquent to an array with ->toArray() or you can convert the array one to a collection with collect($array). Then you can play with them using collection functions. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections